# Remove elements in a numpy array if they differ of a threshold from each other

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am searching for a more pythonic way to filter the elements in a `numpy` array. In my case, I have an array composed of `N` rows and `3` columns.

At the moment, I am doing something like this, but I think there is something that could speed up the 'filtering' of my matrix

```
Threshold = 0.05
i = 0
while i < M.shape[0]:
    j = i + 1
    while j < M.shape[0]:
        if np.abs(M[i,0]-M[j,0]) <=Threshold and np.abs(M[i,1]-M[j,1]) <=Threshold and M[i,2]==M[j,2]:
            M = np.delete(M, (j), axis=0)
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

An example of M is the following:

```
[43.14562 10.96869 116890560]
```

The third column is epoch time.

Comment: It is usually  possible to vectorize these kind of problems, but in your case it is a bit tricky. Anyhow, it might be faster to just create a list of indices that you want to keep or remove, and remove all entries in one go after the loop. Deleting a row on every iteration probably costs `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: can you post a sample of `M`? What is meaning of the second and third condition in the `if` statement?

Comment: I've edited the main post.

Comment: shouldn't the second condition be `np.abs(M[i,1]-M[j,1]) <= Threshold`?